# C# - Rounding the division of integers

Tags: c#, math, multidimensional-array, int, rounding

Windows, C#, VS2010.

My app has this code:

```
int[,] myArray=new int[10,2];
int result=0;
int x=0;
x++;
```

Like below, if the result is between 10.0001 and 10.9999; result=10

```
result= (myArray[x,0]+myArray[x+1,0])/(x+1);
```

I need this:
if the result>=10&&result<10.5 rounds to 10.
if the result between >=10.500&&<=10.999 rounds to 11.

Try the codes below. But not worked.

```
result= Math.Round((myArray[x,0]+myArray[x-1,0])/(x+1));
```

Error: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
'System.Math.Round(double)' and 'System.Math.Round(decimal)'

Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. 
An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
result= Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round((myArray[x,0]+myArray[x-1,0])/(x+1)));
```

Error: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 
'System.Math.Round(double)' and 'System.Math.Round(decimal)'

Thanks in advance, ocaccy pontes.

Comment: When you encounter an error message, it's worth running a google search of the error message or code - that can usually give you a solution.

Comment: Thank you Fabian, really I running a google search and I try to fix this problem, but I was very slow in the race. Your answer was objective and useful. I appreciate your comment, thank you. ocaccy pontes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
result= (int)Math.Round((double)(myArray[x,0]+myArray[x-1,0])/(x+1));
```

That should iron out your compiler errors.

The first one ("Error: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Math.Round(double)' and 'System.Math.Round(decimal)'") is resolved by converting the dividend to a `double`, which 'trickles down' such that the output of the division is *also* a `double` to avoid loss of precision.

You could also explicitly convert the function argument to a `double` for the same effect:

```
Math.Round((double)((myArray[x,0]+myArray[x-1,0])/(x+1)));
```

(Note the placement of the parentheses).

The second error ("Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)") is fixed by explicitly converting the return value of `Math.Round` to an `int`.

Comment: "is resolved by explicitly converting the function argument to a `double`." <- That misled me for a moment. You're converting the dividend to `double`, that makes the division take place at type `double` and all is fine. Reading that sentence, I first thought you'd left the division be an integer division (and hence the conversion and rounding pointless). Perhaps reformulate that.

Comment: shorter: `Math.Round((myArray[x,0]+myArray[x-1,0])/(x+1.0))`, no need to cast

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a 3 year old question, but this answer seems to work well.  Maybe someone will find these extension methods of value.

```
// Invalid for Dividend greater than 1073741823.
public static int FastDivideAndRoundBy(this int Dividend, int Divisor) {
    int PreQuotient = Dividend * 2 / Divisor;
    return (PreQuotient + (PreQuotient < 0 ? -1 : 1)) / 2;
}

// Probably slower since conversion from int to long and then back again.
public static int DivideAndRoundBy(this int Dividend, int Divisor) {
    long PreQuotient = (long)Dividend * 2 / Divisor;
    return (int)((PreQuotient + (PreQuotient < 0 ? -1 : 1)) / 2);
}
```